# What makes a legal constructor, what would make a constructor illegal?

Tags: java, constructor

Hello I taking Computer Science 1, and working on understanding constructors in java.

There is a question in my book asking:

what is wrong with the following code?

```
public C7e2()
{
   C7e2 r;
   r= new C7e2;
}
```

I know you can write the instance variables as C7e2 r = new C7e2 ();
Once I created a main method this would be a legal program right? Even though it doesn't do anything special.

Any beginner information would be greatly received.

Comment: your constructor is calling itself, basically, you'll get an infinite recursive loop of constructors calling constructors calling constructors...

Comment: @s.bandara: what do you find useless? The OP asks what happens if he compiles and runs the code. He just has to do it to have the answer. No need to ask us. Experiments are a key part of the earning process, and are the basis of every scientific process.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with all that except your assertion that it won't compile. It does. I can't imagine why you would think otherwise.

Comment: @EJP: `new C7e2` won't compile without parentheses.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah yes. Was it too much trouble to say so the first time?

Comment: I'm trying to teach someone to fish instead of giving him fishes. Compiling such simple code is not hard, and the message from the compiler is obvious. And the answer to the original question would thus be even more obvious: what's wrong with this constructor is that it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

That would create an infinite recursion until the stack overflowed. Consider that the `C7e2()` constructor is instantiating another `C7e2` object, which will call the constructor again, which will instantiate another `C7e2`, which will call...

The object's constructor handles creation of new instances of that object. If creation of the object requires another instance of itself to be created, that second instance will require a third, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the class you are trying to create an object of this class. The problem is that this is a recursion and when you create a C7e2 object your program won't work. Do not create objects in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give is perfectly legal, in the sense that it is syntactically correct Java code and will compile, once you fix the missing parentheses. But it won't *execute,* as it involves an infinite recursion on `C7e2().`